# how many people can access the web server at once?

Tags: linux, requests

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you do Load Testing and Capacity Planning for Web Sites](https://serverfault.com/questions/350454/how-do-you-do-load-testing-and-capacity-planning-for-web-sites)

That's a simple question. I am curious to how many people can access the web server at once on Linux?

My client said he expects hundreds of people to access the different videos at once but I am not sure if it's possible to do that on non-streaming media server. Has anyone done that?

Comment: Too broad of a question. It's like asking "How much is enough?" The answer depends on many factors, such as CPU, memory, bandwidth, efficiency of the code, platform, etc., etc.

Comment: Also, how much wood would a wood chuck chuck if a wood chuck could chuck wood? That one's had me stumped for years.

Comment: I am discussing sending videos from a NON-STREAMING Media server. Streaming media server is designed for providing videos to thousands of users at once. That's their claim. I don't hear the same for web servers therefore I elaborate about accessing webserver (not media server) to send videos.

Comment: But again, there are too many factors that you've left out of your question. You can stream many more videos from your Quad core server than I can from my Pentium 2 workstation. Can you give us some detail on the hardware being used, web platform, etc.?

Comment: It doesn't sound like you know enough about what you're asking.  If you repost this question, consider the questions everywhere here is asking you:  How are the videos being delivered to the visitors?  What kinda of hardware is this web server running?  What sort of bandwidth does the server have access to?  Which web server platform is the server running?  Is the server also running other platforms or datases?  MySQL?  PHP?  Perl?  How many sites does the web server host?  Does the server offer other services that might interfere with delivering video?  FTP?  Shell?  Torrent?  HTTP Downloads?

Comment: i think this question can be answered quite well...

Answer (score 0):

That sort of thing is quite possible, it just depends on how the web server itself (there are several possible web-server packages for Linux) is configured. Thousands are easily within possibilities. For video you're much more likely to run into bandwidth constraints before you run into concurrent user constraints, though.